# Ring level shift in Win NT based OS

Tags: winapi, x86

Can anyone please tell me how there is privilege change in Windows OS.

I know the user mode code (RL:3) passes the parameters to APIs.

And these APIs call the kernel code (RL:1).

But now I want to know, during security(RPL) check is there some token that is exchanged between these RL3 API and RL1 Kernel API.

if I am wrong please let me know (through Some Link or Brief description) how it works.

Please feel free to close this thread if its offtopic, offensive or duplicate.

> RL= Ring Level
>
> RPL:Requested Privilege level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrupt handlers and the `syscall` instruction (which is an optimized software interrupt) automatically modify the privilege level (this is a hardware feature, the ring 0 vs ring 3 distinction you mentioned) along with replacing other processor state (instruction pointer, stack pointer, etc).  The prior state is of course saved so that it can be restored after the interrupt completes.

Kernel code has to be extremely careful not to trust input from user-mode.  One way of handling this is to not let user-mode pass in pointers which will be dereferenced in kernel mode, but instead HANDLEs which are looked up in a table in kernel-mode memory, which can't be modified by user-mode at all.  Capability information is stored in the HANDLE table and associated kernel data structures, this is how, for example, `WriteFile` knows to fail if a file object is opened for read-only access.

The task switcher maintains information on which process is currently running, so that syscalls which perform security checks, such as `CreateFile`, can check the user account of the current process and verify it against the file ACL.  This process ID and user token are again stored in memory which is accessible only to the kernel.

The MMU page tables are used to prevent user-mode from modifying kernel memory -- generally there is no page mapping at all; there are also page access bits (read, write, execute) which are enforced in hardware by the MMU.  Kernel code uses a different page table, the swap occurs as part of the `syscall` instruction and/or interrupt activation.

Comment: Great, Is it possible for another program to imitate a high privilege program???????

Comment: @Kislay: I already answered that: "This process ID and user token are again stored in memory which is accessible only to the kernel."  Only kernel-mode code can circumvent permission checks.  "Privilege escalation" attacks involve finding a kernel-mode component (perhaps a poorly written device driver) that uses data from user-mode inappropriately, and can be convinced to execute code in kernel mode or change data that only the kernel can access.

Comment: That these handlers elevate the privilege level _automatically_ is not quite true - they do so because the CPU state which defines such behaviour (the Protected Mode's _Descriptor Tables_) has been set up in such a way by the OS that e.g. on interrupt, a privilege switch is done before dispatching execution to the interrupt handler because the _interrupt gate_ for that interrupt vector has been set up so that the _target code segment_ is _a privileged code segment_. This sound like nitpicking but actually is significant - OS writers _must explicitly express_ the intent to privilege switch.

Comment: To clarify: Yes, it is _possible_ to define e.g. an interrupt handler that runs in user mode; all that's needed is the ability to stash an interrupt gate into the IDT whose target code segment is in ring 3. This kind of thing isn't often done, agreed.

Comment: @FrankH: The switch is done in hardware.  I guess what you're saying is that the privilege level switched to is configurable.  Does this edit make my answer more accurate?

Comment: @Ben: I'd argue that programmability of the privilege switching mechanism makes it the software's choice whether the privilege switch happens or not; the hardware only executes what you tell it (through the gate descriptors) to do. x86 is different there from most other CPU architectures, where e.g. certain CPU instructions always (nonconfigurably) cause a privilege switch. On x86, a privilege switch _can_ happen on certain events / instructions if and only if the operating system has programmed the CPU to do so.

Comment: @FrankH: So is "leave the privilege level alone" an actual possibility, or is it just possible to configure a particular interrupt vector to always have ring 3 instead of ring 0?

Comment: Yes, it is possible _not to switch_. The problem with that in practice e.g. for interrupts (hardware-bound ivecs, anyway) is that they can occur at any time in any context; but all userspace / ring3 memory mappings tend to be different, there'd be no guarantee the handler's address exists (mapped in all processes). Else - `#DF`; no good. What happens on interrupt dispatch is no different from what happens on a far call, the target code segment RPL determines whether a privilege switch happens when invoked. Ints/Traps/syscalls are "implicit far calls", target is set in the gate descriptor.

Comment: Ok, last thing ... _leaving the privilege level alone_ is indeed not possible for events that can _occur in any privilege level_. Meaning that the target privilege level is determined / fixed (it's the PL of the target code segment), and if whatever (event or explicit instruction) invokes this runs at a different priv level, it'll switch (to higher PL) or do a far call without PL switch (on equal PL) or `#GP` (on an attempt to switch to lower PL). Maybe I should write an answer  detailing this stuff ... when I've got a little more time ;-)